# "hypotension" due to carbamazepine in open FDA?

Tags: openfda

How to search count of specific adverse event "hypotension" due to carbamazepine in [openFDA](https://open.fda.gov/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to query for that is with the following URL:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.generic_name:carbamazepine%20AND%20patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt:hypotension&limit=10

If you are looking for a graphical representation, you can use a tool my company developed which is completely free and shows this information in a web page at the following URL:

http://www.researchae.com/adverseevent?from_date=1900-01-01&to_date=2014-07-16&from_age=&to_age=&country=GLOBALLY&patientsex=&manufacturername=&drugbrandname=&druggenericname=carbamazepine&medicinalproduct=&reactionmeddrapt=hypotension&drugclass=&drugindication=&indsubmit=&productndc=&safetyreportid=

Comment: Hey, Mark, I still have http://openfdasearch.herokuapp.com/ in my browser history. Is that the same as www.researchae.com (looks like it, but...)  If it is, maybe you should redirect folks so you can narrow in on a canonical URL.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks a lot. Your tool is really helpful and worth recommending others.